# Transition between Views in React Native without maintaining a Stack

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

In my react native project, I am creating a game which has the user progressing between views, but without maintaining a stack.

Each view will have it's own custom back button, but this will not be a standard back button e.g. top left corner in iOS.

Between each change of view though, I require a transition animation. Most will be a fade in, but others are custom.

I have built a navigator from https://reactnavigation.org but am using .reset to ensure a stack of views is not created. However, this seems to stop the transitions from firing (I could be wrong).

Is there a more simple way of switching views with a transition than using reset on a navigator?

Comment: I don't know if this is gonna work but I think it should. If reset stops the transition you can reset the stack right after the transition done. I mean at the new screen. This way you can have your transition and then reset the stack.

Comment: What if you try this to replace the view, i think currently there's no built in method so this is a nice work around - https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/replace-a-screen-using-react-navigation-a503eab207eb

Answer (score 0):

```
//MyApp is your StackNavigator
const defaultGetStateForAction = MyApp.router.getStateForAction;

MyApp.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  // custom action.type will be used
  if (state && action.type === 'CustomBack') {
    // create new routes object with just one route since you want to reset
    const routes = [
      {routeName: action.routeName, params: action.params},
    ];
    // Above routes object will replace your previous state.routes stack
    return {
      ...state,
      routes,
      index: routes.length - 1,
    };
  }
  // if action.type !== 'CustomBack', then use built in method
  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Now that the custom navigation action is ready, u call it using navigation.dispatch on button press from the required screen.

```
  this.props.navigation.dispatch({
    type: 'CustomBack',
    routeName: 'ScreenToBePushed',
    params: {id: 'some params here if you want'}
  });
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/routers/#Custom-Navigation-Actions
This link should provide u with more details on this topic and hope the animation works .